# Xcode 6.1 and iOS Simulator 8.1 very slow to run

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode6.1

I'm using Xcode 6.1 and iOS Simulator 8.1. It takes a long time to run the simple apps that I've written  using the iOS Simulator. Build process was ok but then the iOS Simulator will show the black blank launch screen then the app screen for like 5 minutes before the app launch. Many times it shows error "Lost connection to iPhone 6(/5/4s)". Tried to re-start Xcode and iOS Simulator, and MacBook Pro multiple times already. Tried to reset "Content and Settings" in the iOS Stimulator, but doesn't help.

What could be the possible causes? Any advice/solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you boot up the device that you want to use prior to the Build&Run in Xcode.  If you hit Build&Run in Xcode while the device is not booted, you will need to wait for the device to boot.  This can take a long time depending on your I/O load (eg: if Spotlight is indexing at the same time you are trying to boot, or if your home directory is on a slow volume like a network mount).

Just open up iOS Simulator.app ahead of time and select the device you want to test on from the Hardware->Devices menu.  Then it will be ready when you need it.

Comment: I had iOS Simulator opened prior to build&run already. Thanks Jeremy anyway for the suggestion, it does help save some time with the indexing. But it still doesn't solve the root of problem, it keep taking a long time to run and give "Lost connection to iPhone" error. Googled on this issue and some said it's a Xcode bug with the 6.1 beta, but I had the 6.1 release version installed. So desperate that I decided to upgrade my 3 years old MacBook Pro RAM and harddisk to SSD. Problem solved with the upgrade! The iOS Simulator runs normally now.

Comment: The "lost connection with..." error is usually another issue due to a race launching the app.  If spotlight is indexing a lot, then that is the root of the problem and you just need to wait.  Yes, an SSD will certainly help your I/O throughput ;)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure 'slow animations' is not selected under the Debug tab in the iOS Simulator.  That fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Googled on this issue and some said it's a Xcode bug with the 6.1 beta, but I had the 6.1 release version installed alreadt. I even try the 6.2 beta, hoping Apple has a fix for this, but no luck, still the same.

So desperate that I decided to upgrade my 3 years old MacBook Pro RAM and harddisk to SSD. Problem solved with the upgrade! The iOS Simulator runs normally now.